# Let $A$ be a subset of $B$ with $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$, and let $r$ be an integer $m≤r≤n$...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $A$ be a subset of $B$ with $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$, and let $r$ be an integer $m≤r≤n$. Show the number of $r$ element subsets of $B$ which contain $A$ as a subset is ${n-m}\choose{r-m}$.

- We vaguely covered the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle and how it's related to the  Addition Principle in class, although I am really not sure how to utilize it to solve this proof, any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  You should indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It has nothing to do with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle. It is just a counting argument.

Hint 2: We want to construct a set $S \subseteq B$ with $|S|=r$. We also want $A$ to be a subset of $S$, and so we already know that the $m$ elements of $A$ must be included in $S$. How many elements of $S$ are we free to choose? In how many different ways can we choose them from $B$?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle here.

To select a subset with $r$ elements from set $B$ that contains set $A$, we must select each of the $m$ elements in set $A$.  In how many ways can this be done?

> $$\binom{m}{m}$$

We must also select $r - m$ of the remaining $n - m$ elements in set $B$.  In how many ways can this be done?

> $$\binom{n - m}{r - m}$$

Multiply.